Pip install reports incorrect version
This is more annoying than a real issue as it doesn't seem to be causing me any problems.  But I'm curious if anyone knows what's going on here?  Why does pip keep recommending an upgrade when the package is already at latest version?
This issue seems similar but I've already updated the target to the same site-packages
⦔  python --version
Python 3.9.16

⦔  pip --version                                                                   
pip 24.1.2 from /home/fkhawaja/.virtualenvs/mdata/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)

⦔  grep version /home/fkhawaja/.virtualenvs/mdata/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/__init__.py 
__version__ = "24.1.2"

⦔ pip config list
global.target='/home/fkhawaja/.virtualenvs/mdata/lib/python3.9/site-packages'


So all these are consistent and point to the same location and report version as 24.1.2. However... pip list and pip show pip return different values.
⦔  pip list -v | grep ^pip                                                         
pip                  22.0.4   /home/fkhawaja/.virtualenvs/mdata/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip

⦔  pip show pip
Name: pip
Version: 22.0.4
Summary: The PyPA recommended tool for installing Python packages.
Home-page: https://pip.pypa.io/
Author: The pip developers
Author-email: distutils-sig@python.org
License: MIT
Location: /home/fkhawaja/.virtualenvs/mdata/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: 


on install of a package, pip recommends upgrading pip
⦔  pip install requests
Collecting requests
...
...

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 22.0.4 -> 24.1.2
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip


I'm not sure what's going on.
